# Use JSON,AJAX & JQuery to retrieve and display the Guardian API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve the news titles from the guardian by using their API. As mentioned, I'm using JSON, AJAX and Jquery. My Jquery code is below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url: "https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.response.results.length; i++) 
        {
        $('#head-article').append("<h1>" + data.response.results[i].webTitle + "</h1>");
        }
        console.log(data);
        }
    });
 });
```

Where have I went wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: The code works for me as-is. What do you see in the console? Any errors? I assume you have an element with `id="head-article"`? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/L6130jec/

Comment: Please update your question with the error message.

Comment: HI - yes i do  <div id="head-article" class="thumbnail article">
            </div>

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you just shared your API key in a public forum. That's probably a no-no.

Having just tested this in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nd7svrev/), I don't see any problem and the code returns 10 results. You need to check the ID of your HTML element `head-article` and you need to confirm what results you're getting in your browser debugger console.